# Is it possible to use custom text for the <li> tag bullet?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to use a character instead of a picture for the li tag. I can't find any help on Google.
I know about `list-style-image: url(myimage.gif)` but I don't want to use a picture because it is not scalable and it doesn't look good on retina.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean "can I use some text instead of a bullet point or an image"?

if so, the css [`:before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore) can help:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
  content: '* ';
}
```

Obviously replace "* " with your choice of text.

You can use normal CSS on the `:before` element to style as you like. For example:

```
li:before {
  content: '> ';
  font-family: 'wingdings';
  font-weight:  bold;
}
```

You could get scalable graphics by combining this technique with an SVG font like [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are other options.

The ::marker CSS pseudo-element:

```
li::marker {
    content: '> ';
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

(However, ::marker doesn't seem to be fully supported on Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#browser_compatibility)

Using text in list-style-type:

```
li {
  list-style-type: '> ';
}
```

Great reference on this topic: https://web.dev/css-marker-pseudo-element/